# lighttpd reverse proxy rewrite

Tags: reverse-proxy, lighttpd, rewrite

I am trying to configure `lighttpd` (v1.5) as a reverse proxy. [Gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum) is running on port 8080 and I've setup `lighttpd.conf` as per the following:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/wiki.*" {
    proxy-core.protocol = "http"
    proxy-core.backends = ("127.0.0.1:8080")
    proxy-core.rewrite-request = ("_uri" => ("^/wiki(.*)" => "/$1"))
    proxy-core.rewrite-response = ("_url" => ("^/(.*)" => "/wiki/$1"))
}
```

Requests are being forwarded fine, but links are not being rewritten. The situation appears similar to [lighttpd 1.5 reverse-proxy to trac](https://serverfault.com/questions/230974/lighttpd-1-5-reverse-proxy-to-trac) in so much as browsing to

```
http://192.168.1.1/wiki/
```

loads the page, but without any of it's resources (CSS, etc.) and following a link does not include the `/wiki` infix, e.g.:

```
http://192.168.1.1/pages
```

How do the rewrite rules work in this situation?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're intending the rewrite rules to do (original URL, rewritten URL examples)?  Seems like the `?` in the request rule is intended to be a `/`.

Comment: Sorry, the `?` was a typo. To confirm, I'd like to be able to browse to `http://192.168.1.1/wiki` which is a proxy to a service running on `http://192.168.1.1:8080`. Original URLs on that service are like: `http://192.168.1.1:8080/edit/Home`, which I'd like rewritten to `http://192.168.1.1/wiki/edit/Home`.

Comment: Oh, gotcha.  The response rewrite unfortunately only translates redirection URLs in the headers - those found in the response code aren't translated.  If the wiki's links are sending to absolute locations (with a leading slash), then unfortunately, you can't have lighttpd take care of it for you - you'll need to wrangle the application into sending the correct references in its content.